# Javascript Error BABEL_PARSE_ERROR - ATOM

Tags: javascript, parsing, babeljs

I am writing JavaCcript code with Atom. When I run script, I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\gri10\Desktop\test.html: Unexpected token (1:0)

> 1 | <!DOCTYPE html>
    | ^
  2 | <html>
  3 | <head>
  4 |
    at Parser._raise (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:776:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:769:17)
    at Parser.raise (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:737:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9253:16)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10743:20)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10318:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10298:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10276:23)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10141:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\gri10\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10115:23) {
  loc: Position { line: 1, column: 0 },
  pos: 0,
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR'
}
[Finished in 3.543s]
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse HTML files as javascript files. Can you update your question with your babeljs config please?

Comment: How show you my babeljs config ?